# Capistrano cannot precompile assets, takes hours and nothing happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, assets

I was redesigning hour application recently and added a lot of new images to `assets/images`. When I tried to deploy the application to the server, it's processing until this line:

```
 * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/myapp-staging/releases/20150925042432 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
```

It took so long to finish this command that I kept it running overnight. After 6-7 hours, the processing of precompiling (and deploying) wasn't finished, it stuck on this command.

Before everything was working for more than a year flawlessly.
The app is written in Rails 4 and using Capistrano v2.

Any ideas what it's happening? I've tried to go through similar threads on SO and in some of them was recommended to install `therubyracer` gem, but it didn't help me.

```
group :production do
 gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'
 gem 'execjs'
end
```

I'll be grateful for every help, thank you.

Comment: Noticed that the deploy command is using staging (`RAILS_ENV=staging`) while your `Gemfile` is grouping therubyracer into 'production'.

Comment: Thanks Craig, didn't notice that. I added the same also for the `staging` part and trying to deploy it, but it already lasts 40 minutes, so I am a bit skeptical about it.

Comment: Yeah ... when mine take more than 20 minutes, I usually kill it and start again, which typically helps me get through the hold ups (Rails 4.2 and Cap 2.15.x). Here is what we have in our `Gemfile` regarding `therubyracer` (`gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12', platforms: :ruby`). Might be worth a try ...